# Problem with parallel computing. When I run the pdp::partial() functions on a workflow object

Tags: r, tidymodels

I am using the partial function to calculate two dimensional dependence. The code works fine. Unfortunately, when I add parallel computation commands, an error pops up. I have no idea how to solve it.

```
library(tidymodels)

workflow_fit <-
  workflow() %>%
  add_model(linear_reg() %>% set_engine("lm")) %>%
  add_formula(mpg ~ wt + I(1/disp^2)) %>%
  fit(data = mtcars)


# function pred.var:
pdp_pred_fun <- function(object, newdata) {
  predict(object, newdata, type = "numeric")$.pred
}


cl <- makeCluster(4) 
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)

workflow_partial <-
  partial(workflow_fit,
          pred.var = "disp",
          pred.fun = pdp_pred_fun,
          train = mtcars,
          parallel = TRUE,
          paropts = list(.packages = "earth"))

doParallel::stopImplicitCluster()
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to load the `tidymodels` package in the workers too; PSOCK processes do not inherit the loaded packages in the main process

```r
library(parallel)
library(pdp)
library(tidymodels)

workflow_fit <-
  workflow() %>%
  add_model(linear_reg() %>% set_engine("lm")) %>%
  add_formula(mpg ~ wt + I(1/disp^2)) %>%
  fit(data = mtcars)


# function pred.var:
pdp_pred_fun <- function(object, newdata) {
  predict(object, newdata, type = "numeric")$.pred
}


cl <- makeCluster(4) 
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)

workflow_partial <-
  pdp::partial(workflow_fit,
          pred.var = "disp",
          pred.fun = pdp_pred_fun,
          train = mtcars,
          parallel = TRUE,
          paropts = list(.packages = c("earth", "tidymodels")) # <- add this here
  )
#> Warning: <anonymous>: ... may be used in an incorrect context: '.fun(piece, ...)'

#> Warning: <anonymous>: ... may be used in an incorrect context: '.fun(piece, ...)'

head(workflow_partial)
#>        disp     yhat yhat.id
#> 1  71.10000 31.07171       1
#> 2  86.51923 27.00708       1
#> 3 101.93846 24.64285       1
#> 4 117.35769 23.14762       1
#> 5 132.77692 22.14235       1
#> 6 148.19615 21.43421       1

doParallel::stopImplicitCluster()
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>